# Function works, but fails when util.promisify() used?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have some code using [node-bing-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bing-api). **It's err-first and works perfectly**, but I'd like to convert it to using Promises (and `await`).

I'm using node 8, and `util.promisify`. In the code below, `Bing.web` is the regular err-first code, and `searchBing` is the promisified version.

```
var findParentDir = require('find-parent-dir'),
    configDir = findParentDir.sync(__dirname, 'config.js'),
    config = require(configDir+'config.js'),
    util = require('util'),
    log = console.log.bind(console),
    Bing = require('node-bing-api')({ accKey: config.cognitiveServices.bingSearch }),
    searchBing = util.promisify(Bing.web);

var start = async function(){
    // This fails
    // var searchResultsRaw = await searchBing('windows', {top: 5})
    // log(searchResultsRaw)

    // This works
    Bing.web('windows', {top: 5}, function(err, searchResultsRaw){
        log(searchResultsRaw)
    })
};

start();
```

The promisified version fails with:

```
(node:1752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: this.searchVertical is not a function
```

This is an error inside node-bing-api. But shouldn't `util.promisify` be passing the options on to the real `bing.web` seamlessly, using the same arguments as the original function?

**Why won't this function work when promisified?**

Note I can make my own promisifed version - which works - but I'd rather not create extra code:

```
var searchBing = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Bing.web('windows', {top: 5}, function(err, searchResults){
      if ( err ) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      resolve(searchResults)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: @zubair1024 is there anything about binding or thisContexts in that article or are you spamming?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's probably missing context: the function `Bing.web` is using `this` in its body, which is not bound to `Bing` when using `util.promisify`.

You need to explicitly bind it via:

```
searchBing = util.promisify(Bing.web.bind(Bing));
```

Comment: Thanks. Confirmed this works perfectly and was the cause of the odd error.